# How to do value validation in PostgreSQL (convert my SQL Server syntax to PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I'm migrating database from SQL Server to PostgreSQL with R,
I've searched and tried several ways to do this, but still fail.
I hope someone can provide a similar syntax solution for PostgreSQL.
Below is the syntax I use for SQL Server, and I want to change it to PostgreSQL language

```
  UserValidation <- dbGetQuery(con,paste0("DECLARE @container AS INT = 0
                                                DECLARE @user AS INT
                                              IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 ID FROM dbo.user_information WITH(NOLOCK)
                                                        WHERE userID = '",Username,"')
                                                BEGIN
                                                     SET @user =(SELECT ID FROM dbo.user_information
                                                                 WHERE userID = '",Username,"' AND userpass= '",password,"')
                                                IF(@user IS NULL)
                                                     SET @container = 0
                                                ELSE
                                                     SET @container = 1
                                                END
                                                ELSE
                                                     SET @container = 2
                                              SELECT @container;"))
```

Comment: 1) Don't tag the RDBMS you are migrating from... 2) You need to do your research and have a go before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the T-SQL code, but my understanding is that it returns `0` if the user exists, but the password doesn't match. It returns `1` if the user exists and the password matches, and it returns `2` if the user doesn't exist at all.

If the above assumption is correct, you can do this in a single query without any IFs (btw: the above rule is what you should have put into your question to describe what that query is doing)

```
select case
         when max(user_pass) = '****' then 1 -- user_id and password matches
         when max(user_pass) is null then 2 -- user_id does not match
         else 0 -- user_id matches, but password is different
       end as container 
from user_information
where user_id = 'arthur'
```

This assumes that `user_id` is unique in the table `user_information` and uses the fact that `max()` will always return at least one row. The CASE expression is then used to detect the different conditions.

You need to replace `'****'` with the actual password and `'arthur'` with actual user ID. I hope you are not storing passwords in plain text, and that that `password` value is a hashed version of the real password!